# Allow bpf map_create for specific process or user

Tags: selinux, ebpf

I'm running my program with my own privileged user, and SELinux blocks me from using bpf maps with the next message at */var/log/audit/audit.log*:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1687955676.515:405): avc:  denied  { map_create } for  pid=28935 comm="MyService" scontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0 tclass=bpf permissive=0
```

Of course, turning SELinux enforcement to false or allowing unconfined services explicitly solves the issue, but these are not desired solutions since they hurt security.

Is it possible to tell SELinux to allow my own service/user (and only it) to do anything, without specifying explicitly each and every allow-rule?

I have already tried to use *policycoreutils* and *audit2allow* in order to generate these rule sets but it did not cover everything and exposed my service to other SELinux blockings.